# Does the Pythagorean formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ hold in the plane $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rational-numbers

Does the Pythagorean formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ hold in the plane $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ ?

For example,

The triangle with vertices $(0,0), \ (1,0), \ (0,1) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$  and

$c^2=\sqrt{(0-1)^2+(1-0)^2}=2 \\ \implies c=\sqrt2 
$.

So can I say that changing the field $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, Pythagorean formula does not hold ?

All I want to know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the pythagorean formula holds .

My question is -

when  or in which field pythagorean formula does not hold?

Let me confess that this my confusion.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is your definition of $\cdot$ in your field?

Comment: So you have taken the usual Euclidean distance function on $\Bbb{Q}^2$, which takes values in $\Bbb{R}_{\geq0}$, and now you are surprised that it doesn't take values in $\Bbb{Q}$ only?

Comment: And of course $\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{Q}$ as a product of fields is not a field.

Comment: Maybe you slightly misstated the question and wanted to ask whether $a^2+b^2=c^2$ has rational solutions? Then you already provided a counterexample for given $a=1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: @Servaes, All I want to know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the pythagorean formula holds . My question is - when  or in which field pythagorean formula does not hold?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem isn't about fields, it's about inner products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not *really* about the Pythagorean formula. The problem is that in your "plane over the field $\mathbb Q$", *distance itself* is less well-behaved than over $\mathbb R$. On the "plane" $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$, the Euclidean distance between points $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q$ -- it is, however, an element of $\mathbb R$. Whether or not the Pythagorean theorem still holds does not even factor into that.

Certainly if you have three points $A, B, C$ in $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$, and they form a right angle at $B$, and their pairwise distances are all rational numbers, then the Pythagorean theorem "still" holds in the sense that $\overline{AB}^2 + \overline{BC}^2 = \overline{AC}^2$, as this is just a special case of the Pythagorean theorem in the ordinary plane $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you for nice reply. Actually I was in confusion but you cleared my confusion. Though I feel sad that some others are making as negative of  my question. Better they can edit my question to a suitable form rather than making it negative. I thank you for your different  and nice approach than others